# Need help with exam problem

Tags: homework, electrostatic

[image]

Can somebody please help me with this task:

- Two equally large (r = 5 cm) volume charged non-conductive spheres are fixed so that their centers are a = 1 m away.
- In the middle of the centerline between the spheres we put a charged ball (m = 1 g, the charge is \$ q = +1 \times 10^{-6} \; As \$).
- We push the ball towards the left sphere with velocity of = 20 m/s.

How close to the left sphere ball gets (minimum separation between the ball and the left sphere)? (The charge density for the left sphere is \$ q / V = + 12 \times 10^{-3} \; As/m^{3} \$ , and for the right it is \$ \frac {q}{V} = +9.5 \times 10^{-3} \; As/m^{3} \$.

The gravitational force is neglected.

(Solution x = 16.2 cm From the left ball.)

I tried with equation : \$ 1 / 2 m\times v_2^2 = 1 / 2 m\times v_1^2+ e \times U \; \$
 But I dont know how to calculate voltage(U) between spheres...

Comment: I think you should ask this in the physics stackexchange.

Comment: English is clearly not your first language, and "How many ball approach to the left sphere?" does not make sense to me. Please edit your question, and try a different phrasing.

Comment: My guess is that the question is what is the minimum separation between the ball and the left sphere.

Comment: It would also help if you showed your efforts to solve the problem

Comment: @purplerain: I edited your question for legibility and added MathJAX for the formulas. Check that I have them done correctly. You should be able to figure out how to fix.

Comment: @Transistor: Thank you for editing, everything is correct.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has already been [cross-posted to physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/354506/17516)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some hints:

- Total charge of a homogeneously charged volume is charge densisty times volume
- The electric field created by a homogeneously charged sphere is the same as that of a point charge of same magnitude, and that is \$\boldsymbol{E}(\boldsymbol{r})=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{Q}{r^2}\frac{\boldsymbol{r}}{r}\$
  (assuming origin at point charge)
- You get the total electric field by superpostion of ("adding") fields of both spheres \$\boldsymbol{E}_{total} = \boldsymbol{E}_1 + \boldsymbol{E}_2\$
- Electric force is electric field strength times charge (of probe) \$\boldsymbol{F}_{elec} = q\boldsymbol{E}\$
- Kinetic energy is half mass times velocity squared \$W_{kin}=\frac{1}{2}mv^2\$
- Energy/work is force integrated over space (path) \$W=\int_{path} \boldsymbol{F}_{elec}(\boldsymbol{s}) d\boldsymbol{s}\$

Putting all that together should solve the problem.